# How to end Read() when no new data found

Tags: go, concurrency, io

I'm using github.com/go.bug.st/serial to read from a serial input. I wait for a stream of input. I then get a bunch of data all at one time when the external machine sends me the data. The issue is that there is no end or stop character. When the stream is done, it just stops sending data. The stream is continuous but it is not known how long it will be. I'm assuming I need to use some kind of a timer to basically start a timer of some kind when I start reading and then if I get no new input for two seconds or so, to kill the function so the read ends. I am connecting to an external machine via the serial port. I push a button on this machine at which point it start conducting a test. When the test has completed, it starts streaming data over the serial port. As far as I can see, there is no end character or indication that it is done other than the stream stops.

The data coming over the serial port looks like this:

```
10.2,1
10,2
9.8,2
9.9,3
```

But number of lines I will get is not known and can vary.

I don't know if that's the correct method or if there is an idomatic way to do this. I'm sure I can figure out SOME way of doing this but I figured there must be a better approach.

Below is a very simplied version of what my code is:

```golang
port := OpenPort()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(port)

//the data does come in as lines:
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
mydata := make([]string,0)
for scanner.Scan() {
   line := scanner.Text()
   //assuming a timer needs to go here to say that we've started reading and to somehow 
   // stop once we are no longer getting data. 
   mydata := append(mydata, line)
}
//we never get here because we never stop scanning...

//now use the data once we are done reading the input:
graphFile := MakeGraph(mydata)

err := graph.Render(chart.PNG, graphFile)
if err != nil {panic(err)}
```

Comment: If the system has no protocol to communicate the end of the stream, then there is no idiomatic way to handle it. Use a timeout.

Comment: Those serial port docs say: "// SetReadTimeout sets the timeout for the Read operation ..."
 `SetReadTimeout(t time.Duration) error`

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. I wasn't able to find the source code for the SetReadTimeout other than in the interface definition. I did however switch back to using port.Read(buff) rather than the scanner. The timeout then does a forced read but reads 0 bytes. This at least gives me a token of some kind so I can then break from the loop. I haven't finished the code yet but this does give me a route which will lead to a resolution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I was able to come up with the following solution:

```golang
func ReadData(port serial.Port) string {
  var started bool
  byteBuff := bytes.NewBufferString("")
  buff := make([]byte, 100)
  for {

    n, err := port.Read(buff)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    //if this is the first read, start the timeout
    if !started{
      started = true
      err := port.SetReadTimeout(time.Second * 1)
      if err != nil {panic(err)}
    }

    //0 means we hit the timeout.
    if n == 0{
      return byteBuff.String()
    }

    byteBuff.Write(buff[:n])
  }
}
```

The timeout will basically do a read every second. As there is no data coming in on the line, it will read 0 bytes. Thus the timeout is only started after we start getting data. Thank you @aMike and @JimB.